# CloudFront not caching when Origin header provided

Tags: caching, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

I've set up CloudFront to whitelist the Origin header so it's passed back to S3 if it's provided, in order for CORS to work. Whenever a request is made to CloudFront that has the Origin header, there is a cache miss at CloudFront (as reported by the X-Cache header) and the request takes a lot longer than when the Origin header isn't provided (where the X-Cache header reports the cache was hit).

Is there a way to do CORS with CloudFront but still have the objects cached?

Comment: Are you sending the same origin with each request?

Comment: In testing, yes. Using httpie, issuing the command `http --headers <path to cloudfront object> Origin:http://example.com` repeatedly will always result in "Miss from cloudfront" in the X-Cache header, whereas without the Origin header will always have "Hit from cloudfront". I think I'm doing it right?